# Find equation for hyperbola

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Just taking (failing) a simple algebra class, can't figure this one out and no one can explain it to me and the book just tells me to do it.

> Find an equation for the hyperbola described:
>
> foci at $(-4,0)$ and $(4,0)$; asymptote the line $y=-x$.

So I know that since the numbers on the $x$ axis are changing it will be a horizontal hyperbola. That means $0$ is the center and $c$ is $4$.

I know the slope is $b/a$ for horizontal equations so I know that $b/a = -1$

From that I can get $b = -a$.

This is as far as I can get, my book basically does these steps in the solution manual except they get $-b/a = -1$,   $b=a$   I don't even know why. I can't work past this point without graphing and I know there is suppose to be a way just by working out the algebra but I don't see a solution.

I might not be prepared for this test but I am prepared to fail the test.

Comment: Clearly, you have some "general form" for the equation of a hyperbola, since you are talking about "a", "b", and "c". What is the general form you have?

Comment: The only information I am given is foci at (−4,0) and (4,0); asymptote the line y=−x.

Comment: @Glen: For *this* problem. But you know, **in general**, what equations for "horizontal hyperbolas" look like, don't you? For instance, that they can be written as $$\frac{(x-A)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-B)^2}{b^2} = 1$$for some $A$, $B$, $a$, $b$, or some such **general** thing about hyperbolas? I mean: you immediately jump to say that "c is 4". What is "c"? Then you talk about "b/a". What are b and a relative to the hyperbola? Obviously you have more information about *hyperbolas in general*.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Not exactly sure what you are asking I just know that (x^2)/a - (y^2)/b = 1 is the forumla and that the formula of the slope works in a way that b/a is going to be equal to the slope.

Comment: I know that a is the distance from the center to the vertci or in this problem h+/-a and that b is the distance from the center to the conjugate axis and that c is center to the focus.

Comment: @Glen: The "standard" East-West opening hyperbola with center the origin has equation $x^2/a^2 -y^2/b^2=1$. The foci are at $(\pm c,0)$, where $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. From the comments above, you learned that $a=b$. So $4=\sqrt{2a^2}$. Now you know $a$.

Comment: @Glen: the solution manual gets $a=b$ because this hyperbola has two asymptotes: $y=\frac{b}{a}x$ and $y=-\frac{b}{a}x$, where both $a$ and $b$ are positive. The given asymptote is $y=-x$ and the other one is $y=x$.

Answer (score 4):

So, you know that the equation is going to look like
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1.$$
You already figured out that $a=-b$. So now you need to figure out what values of $a$ and $b$ will make the foci be at the given point $(4,0)$ and $(-4,0)$.

Since you know that $a=-b$, then you know that $a^2=b^2$, so you can rewrite the equation as
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{a^2} = 1$$
or, by clearing denominators (multiplying through by $a^2$)
$$x^2 - y^2 = a^2.$$
Now: where does the hyperbola intersect the $x$ axis? If you have a point $(X,0)$ in the hyperbola, then plugging it in you will have
$$X^2 = a^2.$$
So if you can determine where the hyperbola intersects the $x$-axis, you can use that to figure out the value of $a$, and so the value of $b$, and so the equation for the hyperbola.

**Note:** There are many, many, many ways to finish the problem, depending on what you know about hyperbolas in general (which is *precisely* why I asked you in comments what you knew).

**Added.** One possible way to finish the problem is to use the  eccentricity of the hyperbola. The distance from the center to the foci is $a\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity of the hyperbola. The eccentricity is always equal to
$$\varepsilon = \sqrt{ 1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}}$$
so here, since $a=b$, that means that the eccentricity is $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore, since the distance from the center to the foci is $4$, this tells you that $4 = a\varepsilon = a\sqrt{2}$. You now know what $a$ is, and thus, you know what $a^2=b^2$ is, and so you know the equation of the hyperbola.

**Added 2.** Another possibility you discuss in the comments. You have $a$ is the distance from the center to the vertices; $b$ is the distance from the center to the conjugate axis. These distances satisfy $c^2 = a^2+b^2$, where $c$ is the value $4$ that you have. Since $a^2=b^2$, then you have $c^2=2a^2$, or $c = \sqrt{2a^2} = \sqrt{2}|a| = a\sqrt{2}$. You already know what $c$ is, so now you can solve for $a$. Once you know $a$, you also know $b$ (since $a=-b$) which gives you the information you need.

Comment: Mind blown! I have never seen anything like that with all these circle, ellipse, parabola and hyperbola problems. Most likely the test will all be stuff like that. thank you Actualyl I still can't figure this one out at all. I just can't figure anything out.

Comment: Sorry this is just incredibly frustrating for me that I can't figure any of this stuff out on my own. This is why I fail all my tests I guess, I can't figure out the hard problems without help and that is all the test is. I have no idea what e is and we never used that in class, my book just does the transverse axis in the x asix, c=4 using the slop of the asymptote -b/a = -1 = b=a b^2+b^2 = 16 b=square root of 8 a= square root of 8

Comment: There are multiple ways of getting the missing information; eccentricity is one of them. You can also use other information, but what you write is not correct: you should **not** use the = sign between the equation that says $-b/a=1$ and the equation that says $b=a$. I'll add your way.

Comment: @Glen: I edited your comment to remove the possibly offensive language.

Comment: @Willie: It doesn't particularly offend me, but I do notice that the site is kept pretty "clean", which is why I mentined it.

Answer (score 3):

As the foci are on the $x$-axis and symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis,
the equation of the hyperbola is

$$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1.$$

Such an hyperbola has two asymptotes:

$$y=\frac{b}{a}x\qquad\text{and}\qquad y=-\frac{b}{a}x,$$ where both $a$ and $b$ are positive. The given asymptote is $y=-x$ and the
other one is $y=x$. The equation $y=-\frac{b}{a}x$ should be equivalent to $
y=-x$, which implies that $-\frac{b}{a}=-1$. Hence $b=a$. Now you use the
information on the foci to find $a$. The distance from each focus to the
origin is $c=4$. These numbers are related by the equation $$a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}
.$$ For $b=a$ and $c=4$, we have $a^{2}+a^{2}=16$, thus $a=2\sqrt{2}$ (the
other solution is negative), and the equation of the hyperbola is

$$\frac{x^{2}}{8}-\frac{y^{2}}{8}=1.$$

Comment: érico: My turn: "axis" and "hyperbola". (-: (Hyperbole is an extravagant exaggeration...)

Comment: @Arturo: thanks for correcting me.