# Solve nonliner equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

We are trying to find intersection of hyperbolas and we ended up in five equations
$$\begin{align}
A_1X^2+B_1Y^2+C_1XY+D_1X+E_1Y+F1&=0\\
A_2X^2+B_2Y^2+C_2XY+D_2X+E_2Y+F2&=0\\
A_3X^2+B_3Y^2+C_3XY+D_3X+E_3Y+F3&=0\\
A_4X^2+B_4Y^2+C_4XY+D_4X+E_4Y+F4&=0\\
A_5X^2+B_5Y^2+C_5XY+D_5X+E_5Y+F5&=0
\end{align}$$
We want to find numerical solutions to these equations for $(X,Y)$
so that we can write C++ code.

Appreciate your suggestions and help!

Comment: Two conic sections can intersect in four places. But there is no reason that a third (let alone a fourth and a fifth) would intersect in the same places. So either I do not understand the question, or this cannot be done in general.

Comment: @alex.jordan it appears they want to algorithmically determine if the system is inconsistent first, and then if not determine the intersection points

Comment: Where there hyperbole? There parabola. 5 equations and 2 unknown? Many of the equations. It is necessary to reduce the number of equations.

Comment: Alex: if it doesn't intersect no problem; if it does i should be able to fine solution

Comment: @frogeyedpeas If that is the case, then they should intersect two of the conic sections and then check if the four solutions satisfy the remaining three equations.

Comment: frogeyedpeas: exactly...

Comment: individ: these equations I picked from here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101325/finding-plotting-equation-of-hyperbola-given-foci-and-difference-in-distances/       if less number of equations can also give me solutions I am more than happy

Comment: Are all $F$'s the same, and not indexed? If for any equation, $F$ was nonzero, the equation could be rescaled so that $F$ became $1$. But it is generally possible that $F=0$. So in general, the $F$'s could be a mix of $0$s and $1$s for simplicity.

Comment: alex.jordan : these are different. F1, F2...

Comment: Write 2 equations with numbers. I'll try to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two problems here: 1 proving existence of solutions, 2 finding said solutions

So begin by subtracting your constant terms first to the left hand side:

$$\begin{align}
A_1X^2+B_1Y^2+C_1XY+D_1X+E_1Y&=-F_1\\
A_2X^2+B_2Y^2+C_2XY+D_2X+E_2Y&=- F_2\\
A_3X^2+B_3Y^2+C_3XY+D_3X+E_3Y&=-F_3\\
A_4X^2+B_4Y^2+C_4XY+D_4X+E_4Y&=-F_4\\
A_5X^2+B_5Y^2+C_5XY+D_5X+E_5Y&=- F_5
\end{align}$$

Now given this create variables $u_1 = X^2, u_2 = Y^2, u_3 = XY ... u_5 = Y$ and create a linear system out of this,

now perform gaussian elimination and determine if there are any inconsistent rows in the matrix (if there are, there is no solution). If there are no inconsistent rows nor redundant rows (that is all 0's) we  now must determine if the original form of our system

$$u_1 = G_1 \\ u_2 = G_2 \\ u_3 = G_3  \\ u_4 = G_4  \\ u_5 = G_5  $$

is consistent. Expand these out into their original expressions:

$$X^2 = G_1 \\ Y^2 = G_2 \\ XY = G_3  \\ X = G_4  \\ Y = G_5  $$

And check systematically through substitution. I would say you will have an inconsistent system basically almost all of the time.

Now sometimes as I said you will have redundant rows:

In this case you can eliminate those equations (not necessary) and then commence as usual with a symbolic algorithm of choice, by solving for one of the variables $X$ or $Y$ (via quadratic formula treating the other variable as a constant) and then substituting back into the remaining equations:

Again at this stage we may run into an inconsistent system but if not then a solution will appear:

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this and getting perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the first two equations and solve that system. There will be up to four solutions (assuming that the two equations are not multiples of one another). Then check if the solutions satisfy the other three equations.

---

To solve

$$\begin{align}
A_1X^2+B_1Y^2+C_1XY+D_1X+E_1Y+F_1&=0\\
A_2X^2+B_2Y^2+C_2XY+D_2X+E_2Y+F_2&=0
\end{align}$$

let's assume for now that neither $A_1$ nor $A_2$ are $0$. (If either is $0$, then one equation is linear in $X$, so you can solve for $X$ easily and substitute that into the other equation, resulting in a quartic polynomial in $Y$.)

Then

$$\begin{align}
A_1A_2X^2+B_1A_2Y^2+C_1A_2XY+D_1A_2X+E_1A_2Y+F_1A_2&=0\\
A_1A_2X^2+A_1B_2Y^2+A_1C_2XY+A_1D_2X+A_1E_2Y+A_1F_2&=0
\end{align}$$

and subtracting:

$$\begin{align}
(B_1A_2-A_1B_2)Y^2+(C_1A_2-A_1C_2)XY+(D_1A_2-A_1D_2)X+(E_1A_2-A_1E_2)Y+(F_1A_2-A_1F_2)&=0\\
\end{align}$$

which is linear in $X$. You can solve this and find $X=\frac{Q(Y)}{L(Y)}$ where $Q$ is a quadratic polynomial and $L$ is linear. Then you can substitute this into one of the first equations, clear denominators, and end up with a quartic polynomial in $Y$.

So you end up in a position of having to solve a degree four polynomial. There is a quartic formula you could use. Or you could use numerical root finding methods to solve for $Y$. For each $Y$, you have $X=\frac{Q(Y)}{L(Y)}$.

Comment: No. It won't work. We have to solve the equation of the 4th degree.

Comment: @individ And what would be the problem with that? [Here is how you solve a 4th degree polynomial exactly](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html). Although with OP's purpose in mind, I would just use Newton's method to approximate solutions.

Comment: There are more effective methods. They allow to solve even the system of Diophantine equations.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757664/system-of-diophantine-equations

Comment: @individ "It wont work" and "There are more effective methods" are two different things.

Comment: Alex: I like this answer. though I have not coded this as this might give me 8 solutions. But I might have some situation where I have to handle less number of equation. This will become handy. Thanks

Comment: @Razack Just so you know, it will only give you four solutions. You will have one value of $Y$ for each of the four roots of the resulting degree 4 polynomial. And then $X=\frac{Q(Y)}{L(Y)}$ for each $Y$.

Comment: Alex: Yah Four values.....Thanks

Comment: I got it. 8 solution is wrong max will have 4 solutions. For every Y we will have a X; If we have y1, y2, y3, y4 then there would be four solutions like (x1,y1), (x2, y2),..(x4, y4).